# Synonymize [ui] with [gui]

Tags: discussion, tags

[gui](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gui) has 199 questions and a little wiki info. [ui](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ui) has 20 questions and no tag wiki or excerpt. It appears to cover the same things. Should they be synonymized?

Answer (score 2):

It is done

(More characters so I can post this answer.)